# How to save All excel Charts in one pdf then Email it

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-pdf, cdo.message

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me with this, I am creating a dynamic excel sheet and I managed so far to create excel charts using **`Excel vba`**.

However, I am struggling with exporting all of the charts and one additional sheet to one **`pdf`**. I have around 15 excel charts and one excel sheet that I need to put in one **`pdf`**. And I need the excel sheet to be the first page in the **`pdf`**. Then email this **`pdf`** (all using vba).

Could you please help me on this! Your help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello can you please share or post what you tried so far ?

Comment: try to look here http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-33369.html for chart export and here http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/85086-sending-email-using-visual-basic-applications-excel.html  for email sending

Answer (score 1):

Well you could Publish the workbook to PDF, just make sure your fist page is the first sheet

```
Option Explicit
Sub PDF_And_Mail()
    Dim FileName As String

    '// Call the function with the correct arguments
    FileName = Create_PDF(Source:=ActiveWorkbook, _
                              OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                              OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)

    If FileName <> "" Then
        Mail_PDF FileNamePDF:=FileName
    End If

End Sub

'// Create PDF
Function Create_PDF(Source As Object, OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, _
                                OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
    Dim FileFormatstr As String
    Dim Fname As Variant

    '// Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
    If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

            '// Open the GetSaveAsFilename dialog to enter a file name for the pdf
            FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
            Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                                                  Title:="Create PDF")

        '// If you cancel this dialog Exit the function
        If Fname = False Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        'If OverwriteIfFileExist = False we test if the PDF
        'already exist in the folder and Exit the function if that is True
        If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
            If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Exit Function
        End If

        'Now the file name is correct we Publish to PDF
        Source.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=Fname, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish

        'If Publish is Ok the function will return the file name
        If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then
            Create_PDF = Fname
        End If
    End If
End Function


'// Email Created PDF
Function Mail_PDF(FileNamePDF As String)
    Dim GMsg As Object
    Dim gConf As Object
    Dim GmBody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set GMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set gConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    gConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = gConf.Fields

    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "GmailAddress@gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    GmBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    With GMsg
        Set .Configuration = gConf
        .To = "recip@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = "Reply@something.com"
        .Subject = "Important message"
        .TextBody = GmBody
        .AddAttachment FileNamePDF
        .Send
    End With

End Function
```

> *Most codes from* [*Ron de Bruin*](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/pdf.htm)

Comment: I am trying to send the pdf from my gmail account. I found a script online, but although "Email was sent" message appears, nothing happens. I followed this link: http://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/send-email-using-gmail-with-excel-vba/

Comment: No, I couldn't solve the problem yet. I looked at other videos and read some articles and forums; I tried different server port but nothing worked for me.